# Travelling to mexico on B1-B2 visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, international-travel, mexico

I am an Indian citizen and have a valid USA B1-B2 visa on my Indian passport, can I travel to Mexico from Ecuador for tourism purpose with valid USA B1-B2 visa?

Answer (score 1):

According to a website from the [Mexican government](http://www.inm.gob.mx/index.php/page/paises_visa/en.html):

> A foreign who has any of the following documents shall not require Mexican visa:
>   ...
>   b) Valid visa from the United States of America;

So it seems like you should be fine.